# C# DTLS implementation that uses X509Certificate2 certificates

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, coap

I am trying to create a CoAP server that uses certificate-based DTLS to encrypt the data in transmission.  I am using the [CoAP-CSharp Nuget package](https://github.com/Com-AugustCellars/CoAP-CSharp) to set up the server, however, I am not having much joy in getting our RSA X509 certificates to work with it. There does not seem to be much documentation on how to translate the X509Certificate2 object into the required OneKeys for the DTLSEndPoint.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: At least summer 2018, x509 simply wasn't supported by that c-Sharp implementation (see [c-Sharp-x509-client](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/issues/655#issuecomment-394586104). And for CoAP ECDSA is much more common than RSA. So, I would recommend to check, if this is suppported in the meantime, and if it supports only ECDSA or RSA as well.

Comment: Thanks, Achim, this is indeed correct. Currently, the package only supports ECDSA SHA256 certificates.  I managed to get it to work by replacing our RSA certificates with ECDSA certificates.

Answer (score 0):

```
public TlsKeyPair(byte[] certificate, OneKey privateKey)

public TlsKeyPair(X509CertificateStructure[] certificateArray, OneKey privateKey)
```

The one key seems to be the private key for your certificate, not the certificate itself. Ensure, that you have access to that private key, otherwise it will not be possible to execute such an handshake.